# Possible to add basic HTTP access authentication via HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy, http-authentication

I've successfully setup HAProxy in front of an HTTP server which I have **no control over**.

Is it possible to configure HAProxy to add [Simple HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to all sites, bearing in mind I can't configure this on the backend?

Thanks,

Lars

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had to do this today myself (because IIS 7.5 bizarrely doesn't actually support authenticating against anything but Windows user accounts or AD!)...

Here's all the code

```
userlist UsersFor_AcmeCorp
  user joebloggs insecure-password letmein

backend HttpServers
  .. normal backend stuff goes here as usual ..
  acl AuthOkay_AcmeCorp http_auth(UsersFor_AcmeCorp)
  http-request auth realm AcmeCorp if !AuthOkay_AcmeCorp
```

I documented it a bit better here: http://nbevans.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/cultural-learnings-of-ha-proxy-for-make-benefit/

Comment: +1  Just wanted to add that you can also add the final lines in a `frontend` definition rather than `backend` if you want.  And the `realm xxxx` part is optional.

Comment: I implemented this but what happens is that on every subsequent api calls I get the popup asking for authentication.This makes it unusable.  Is there anyway where it is asked once then cached for the rest of the calls ? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is actually possible, but right now I can only find an example to get you halfway...

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt is your bible.

Check out section 3.4 (Userlists)

It starts:

> **It is possible to control access to frontend/backend/listen sections** or to http stats by allowing only authenticated and authorized users. To do this, it is required to create at least one userlist and to define users.

That section explains how to set up a userlist. The example in that section's quite exhaustive so copy that if you need to.

Next, need to figure out how to apply it... I think the answer lies in section 7.5.3 (Matching at Layer 7)

I think it might be as simple as using the following in an acl:

```
http_auth(userlist)
http_auth_group(userlist) <group> [<group>]*
  Returns true when authentication data received from the client matches
  username & password stored on the userlist. It is also possible to
  use http_auth_group to check if the user is assigned to at least one
  of specified groups.
```

Again, I haven't tested it, but that's what I read the documentation as suggesting is possible.

I hope that's enough to get you started?

Comment: Good shout, i guess i'm just used to it now!

Comment: Although looking at it again, it doesn't seem to have been updated in months... I haven't checked for specific changes between that and the wall of text but assume there is some.

Comment: That 'better' bible link is 404'ing.  Even better would be this http://www.haproxy.org/#docs . There you find HTML/text manual goodies.

Comment: Links for getting at the manuals: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this for the purposes of authenticating an

`option httpchk`

config, this simpler solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325882/haproxy-solr-healthcheck-with-authentication

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.